# How to modify salt-minion settings in WINDOWS without reinstallation

Tags: salt-stack

I have a question about modifying salt minion settings in WINDOWS.
When I try to modify the salt master address or minion name, I have to uninstall and reinstall to input these information.

I tried to find files, registry describing these information, but in vain.
Is there any solution of wisdom?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to modify the Salt Minion's config file which is found here, by default:

c:\salt\conf\minion

Comment: Note that you also need to restart the minion after you modify the configuration.  =)

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you, Jack!  Could you mark the answer as accepted so your question doesn't show up as unanswered?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

‪It's now `C:\ProgramData\Salt Project\Salt\conf\minion`

Activate (if you don't see ProgramData) :
View -> Hidden items